# Azure AD getting wrong token version

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory

My application is based on [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph#step-2--register-the-sample-with-your-azure-active-directory-tenant)
I'm receiving token in my wpf application form login and password like this:

```
result = await _app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordAsync(Scopes, username, securePassword);
```

then I want to access to my secured web api.
But when I try to access I get

> AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS500137: The token
>   issuer doesn't match the api version: A version 1 token cannot be used
>   with the v2 endpoint. Trace ID: 42aaa5f8-0a2c-4c3f-a593-1676fd662700
>   Correlation ID: efe97d3a-ca2f-4dfe-a50c-5c3f4accde9a Timestamp:
>   2019-01-20 15:52:16Z

here

```
AuthenticationResult result = application.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync(scopes.Except(_scopesRequestedByMsalNet), userAssertion).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

What I just found out is that AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync gives v1 or v2 for different registered native applications. I cannot find the difference in configurations on azure between the 2 apps.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot the issue? You received a specific error message. Have you looked into solving that error?

Comment: You are asking for a token from the V1 endpoint (ADAL) and trying to use it with an application that uses the V2 endpoint (MSAL).

Comment: @camiloterevinto I guess end point version is set here __app = new PublicClientApplication(aadClientId, authority);_ Authority is "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0"

Comment: @danielmann Ask me better what I didn't do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it work.

So, what we have:
Native client (name: WpfApp), web api (name: WebApiApp)

Now we want to get access token using login, password and **scopes!**

Assume our config is:

```
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0"/>
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="organizations"/>
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"/>
<add key="todo:TodoListScope" value="https://ourdomain.onmicrosoft.com/WebApiApp/access_as_user"/>
```

To make it work you need to set in **WpfApp manifest** (not just in WebApiApp manifest) accessTokenAcceptedVersion:2

Comment: Thanks, it could help you. You could mark your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the Azure portal, the **App registrations (Preview)** is to register an app in the v2 endpoint, the **App registrations** is to register an app in the v1 endpoint.

The v1 authorization endpoint is like:

```
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/authorize?
```

v1 token endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/token
```

The v2 authorization endpoint is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

v2 token endpoint is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: Just checked it: app registrations (preview), Public client (mobile & desktop) redirect url - https://localhost. Then I had to change it to native client manually by editing the manifest (allowPublicClient:true). Then I checked it in my application - *AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordAsync* gives v1 token (checked in jwt.ms)

Comment: @amplifier, you could change the v1 token endpoint to v2 endpoint.

Comment: how? Could you help me please? I create PublicClientApplication with Authority=https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0
p.s. It seems that v2 can be registered only via https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. But I defenitely can say that somehow I managed to register v2 via portal.azure.com

Comment: In the azure portal, the App registrations (Preview) is also for the v2 app as I mentioned.  And you could check if the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` value is 2 in the app manifest via apps.dev.microsoft.com. If the value is null or 1, it means you app will only accept the v1 token. For this, you need to manually change it to 2 to accept v2 token.

Comment: Changed it from null to 2, AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordAsync still gives v1 token. Btw the application id that gives me v2 token from AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordAsync has accessTokenAcceptedVersion in its manifest

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, finally i figured it out. If you add the client app from Azure AD app registration preview it will give you the v1.0 access token, I created a new client using https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/, it is returning v2.0 end point. At least it worked for me.

Refer picture below, My angular app under converged applications giving me v2.0 token & traffic-lightapp-test under azure ad application is giving me v1.0 token

[image: My angular app under converged applications giving me v2.0 token & traffic-lightapp-test un is giving me v1.0 token]